# How to avoid repetitive XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am currently in the process of creating simple application using WPF and C# (as a learning exercise). I've noticed that I am gonna need two almost identical Pages (same user controls, same list, same methods for buttons etc).  The thing which is gonna be different is content - different text, headers, images displayed.
Avoiding repetetive methods is easy - I'll just create some kind of abstract basic Page which those two Pages are gonna inherit from. But how do I avoid repeating basically entire XAML code? Is there a way to resolve it in a civilized  manner or should I just copy and paste it like a caveman?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: That sounds like a template with the differing control text, images etc bound to properties of a viewmodel.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction mate, I'll look into this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: ...or a UserControl instead of a template; good answer down there from Benjamin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Create UserControls and reuse them**

You don't have to put everything directly into your window. Instead create a UserControl and put your similar controls there. You can then differentiate for example by changing the DataContext or using DependencyPropertys for different use cases. Let's say you name your UserControl `MyUserControl`. You can then include it like this in your Window:

```
<local:MyUserControl x:Name="MemberNameCanBeAccessedInCodeBehind" />
```

**2. Reuse code-behind**

One thing that was a big eye opener for me regarding reusability was the fact that a XAML file and its code-behind file are basically two sides of the same coin. Let's go back to `MyUserControl`. In the XAML file you have:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl" ...
```

And in the code-behind you have:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
```

The thing is: You don't have to inherit from `UserControl`! If you have some code-behind functionality like key-bindings or event handlers you can reuse them by creating your own custom UserControl class:

```
public class MyUserControlClass : UserControl
{
    // Everything that you want to reuse!
}
```

Now you just replace `UserControl` in your XAML and code-behind with `MyUserControlClass` and you can use that functionality:

```
<local:MyUserControlClass x:Class="MyUserControl" ...

public partial class MyUserControl : MyUserControlClass
```

The XAML window might show an error at first but when you compile it works.